# Do I need to send all ViewState fields in JMeter?

Tags: asp.net, jmeter, viewstate

I'm trying to test an ASP.Net web application using JMeter but I am getting an error page in the second step after navigating to another page. I think this is something to do with ViewState. When I inspect the page, the __VIEWSTATEFIELDCOUNT = 33 and they are named __VIEWSTATE1, __VIEWSTATE2 etc.. Why would there be more than 1 ViewState? Do I need to send every one of these as parameters in my request from JMeter?

Thanks, any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably this is due to [ViewState Chunking](https://weblogs.asp.net/jhallal/large-viewstate-amp-viewstate-chunking-maxpagestatefieldlength) so in case of very large ViewState it can be split into several parts as some routers/firewalls limit single request parameter length and large viewstates might not fit into the limitation.

So in order to successfully mimic real browser request you need to correlate **all** the viewstate fields (including `__VIEWSTATEFIELDCOUNT`)

Also don't forget to add [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan to represent browser cookies and deal with cookie-based authentication and correlate other possible dynamic fields like [`__EVENTVALIDATION`](https://www.google.pl/search?q=.net%20eventvalidation&oq=.net%20eventvalidation&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.3408j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

More information: [ASP.NET Login Testing with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/aspnet-login-testing-jmeter)